# SQL DELETE multiple post_meta on single and multi-sites

Tags: posts, post-meta, sql

So I don't have too much knowledge on SQL and running scripts, so I wanted to see if the community can help me.

**Here is what I'm attempting to do**:
Delete all post_meta that has the meta_keys `honorific`, `suffix` and `nickname`.

Here is my attempt which didn't work for single site (*One single wp_postmeta table*):

```
DELETE FROM `wp_postmeta` 
WHERE `meta_key` LIKE 'honorific' 
AND `meta_key` LIKE 'suffix'
AND `meta_key` LIKE 'nickname'
```

When I do just the single post_meta, it works as shown below:

```
DELETE FROM `wp_postmeta` 
WHERE `meta_key` LIKE 'honorific'
```

Also, how can I achieve the same as above but on WP multi-sites?

So let's say that in the DB, I have wp_10_postmeta, wp_11_postmeta, wp_12_postmeta and so on?

All help is appreciated!

Comment: Post meta can't have more than one `meta_key`. You want to delete them where the meta key is one value `OR` another. Not `AND`. For multisite you'll just need to do each table separately.

Comment: @JacobPeattie Thanks so much Jacob, this is where I was making the mistake, the OR conditional worked perfectly.

Comment: @JacobPeattie, is there a way that I can narrow it down to just a single post type from wp_posts?